# Error log in "Manage Categories" page ver. 1.9.1.0

Tags: error, extensions

I installed an extension and somehow it hits me with this serious problem. Even though I uninstall it, the error is still on. Please help me. I cannot access it manage the categories now.

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 535828022979

Comment: Check the record at `/var/report/535828022979` and open it to see what error you got

Comment: Hello Kenn, welcome to Magento SE. Could you please add the record at /var/report/535828022979 here ?

Answer (score 1):

This extension may have modified the database, or changed data during its installation.
To find more information about this error, you should open the file named 535828022979 in the folder **var/report/**

I also suggest you to contact directly the developers of this extension as this question is too much specific for Magento Stack Exchange.